# Facebook Auto Post not working?

Tags: 7, social-network

[image]

I configure the facebook modules. I created facebook Apps and I gave facebook auth id and secret key and all. But I couldn't connect with facebook.  I got this type of Error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You need to provide website URL on your app settings.**

Step 1. Navigate to your app settings

https://developers.facebook.com/apps/[your-app-id]/settings/

Step 2. Under website section provide your website URL.

[check this answer for Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3610858/facebook-login-given-url-not-allowed-by-application-configuration)

Comment: @shrish.I got the answer

Comment: i have some issues also."Something went wrong while posting update to your facebook wall. The error has been captured by watchdog".

Comment: do you have permission to publish contents to facebook? you need to goto facebook app settings and add `publish_actions` permission to your app.